# найти дочерный елемент с конкретным значением innerHtml ()

Tags: jquery

Только начинаю изучать jquery и поэтому не понимаю еще многих вещей.
Задача следующая: нужно найти в родителе дочерний елемент с определенным значением innerHTML. например, нужно найти div c текстом "my" и задать ему бордер

```
 <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">hello</div>
        <div class="child2">my</div>   
        <div class="child3">jquery</div>

    </div>
```

написал следующий код, но он не работает, подскажите  пожалуйста где ошибка

```
 if ($(".parent").children().val() == 'my'){
      $('this').css("border", "1px solid pink")
   }
```

Comment: `console.log($(".parent").children().val());` - ?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что он выведет мне всех children, а мне нужен только один с "my"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('div.child').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === 'my';
}).css("border", "1px solid pink")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1 child">hello</div>
  <div class="child2 child">my</div>
  <div class="child3 child">jquery</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное,  а можно вот так?  $(".parent").children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === 'my';
}).css("border", "1px solid pink")

Comment: @Taras можно. только у вас под них попадут все дети, это могут быть любые теги, даже не те, что вы хотите. лучше сделать срез по конкретным классам

Comment: неверный ответ - будет захвачен`<div class="child2 child"><span>my</span></div>` что не соответствует `innerHtml = 'my'`

Comment: @SanyaH это предсказание, что именно то, что и имел в виду автор ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский :-)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".parent").find(":contains('my')").css("border", "1px solid pink")
// для точного совпадения:
$(".parent").children().filter((i, e) => e.innerHTML === 'my').css("border", "1px solid pink");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">hello</div>
        <div class="child2">my</div>   
        <div class="child3">jquery</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, по вашему варианту будет  искать в любом атрибуте дива, да? а как сузить поиск только для  значение между скобками, не знаю как это правильно назвать value или innerHTML       <div>my</div>

Comment: вариант неправильный. потому что contains !== точное совпадение

Comment: `:contains('my')` - найти всех детей, в которые содержат текст "my". При это нужно помнить, что учитывается регистр и неполное совпадение ("my name" тоже выберется)